# Ineqaulity constrains issue

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout, autolayout

I have the issue with inequality constrains. I want to have facebook_logo.Top constrain equal = 136, but when for example, keyboard appears i would like to scroll view to top and in this case facebook logo can be hidden, to achieve it i added second constrain. So now i have two constrains:

- facebook_logo.Top Layout <=136
- facebook_logo.Top Layout >= -100

And it working for me, but Xcode shows autolayouts error: Inequality Constrain Ambiguity.

Can you please advice how to fix it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually I have found my problem, to resolve it I removed constrain facebook_logo.Top Layout and added anothe one facebook_logo.Bottom Layout. now all UI elements pinned to bottom layout guide and views can be shifted to top when kwyboar appears. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should listen to keyboard notifications like this:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(vc, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: "UIKeyboardWillShowNotification", object: nil)

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(vc, selector: "keyboardWillHide:", name: "UIKeyboardWillHideNotification", object: nil)
```

and modify the constraints according with the `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey and UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` in the userInfoDictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Put all views in scrollview, give proper constraints then use IQKeyboardManager. it will manage itself.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a constraint equal `facebook_logo.Top Layout = 136` and play with priority exp :

- `facebook_logo.Top Layout =   136` -> priority : 999
- `facebook_logo.Top Layout <=  136` -> priority : 1000
- `facebook_logo.Top Layout >= -100` -> priority : 1000

Comment: unfortunately it's not working,  xcode error disappears, but logo image will not be shifted to top.

Comment: you should play around with constraints priority value. I am sure you will find the best configuration that works fine for all device's screen sizes